# NullPointerException in Processing, Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, processing

I'm hoping some of you are familiar with the Processing development environment for Java. I've searched the site, but wasn't able to find too much. So I'm supposed to be passing command-line arguments from the 'args' string array from

```
public static void main(String[] args )
```

...to arrays in a setup() function so that I can parse them and use them as values for the heights of bar graphs, which are to be drawn on a graphical window. I don't understand why I keep getting a NullPointerException error at line 16...

```
for(int i = 0; i < tempArgs.length; i++) {
    dataArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempArgs[i]);
}
```

.....as I thought the tempArray array should have values in it, which seems to be bourne out by the System.out.println statement I used to test this at the end of the main method. Here's the whole code, it's quite short. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class Main extends PApplet {
    int[] dataArray ;
    int[] normalizedData;
    String[] tempArgs;

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        /*size(dataArray[2], dataArray[3]);
        smooth();
        background(255);*/
        for(int i = 0; i < tempArgs.length; i++) {
            dataArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempArgs[i]);
        }

        int max = dataArray[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
            if(dataArray[i] > max) {
                max = dataArray[i];
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
            normalizedData[i] = (dataArray[i] / max) * (height - 20);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < normalizedData.length; i++) {
            fill(255,34,65);
            rect(3, 5, 10, normalizedData[i]);
        }

        size(dataArray[2], dataArray[3]);
        smooth();
        background(255);

     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tempArgs = new String[args.length + 2];
        tempArgs[0] = "--bgcolor=#FFFFFF";
        tempArgs[1] = "project1.Main";
        for(int i = 2; i < tempArgs.length; i++) {
            tempArgs[i] = args[i-2];
        }
        System.out.println(tempArgs.length);
          PApplet.main(tempArgs);          
    }
}
```

Comment: stacktrace? what line is your null pointer on?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < tempArgs; i++)

Comment: It must be the tempArgs array, but I don't understand how, nor how to fix it.

Comment: Since `tempargs[0]` is "--bgcolor=#FFFFFF" and `tempargs[1]` is "project1.Main", `Integer.parseInt(tempArgs[i])` is probably not what you want.

Comment: You're absolutely right. After changing it to this...                                                                                                for(int i = 0; i < tempArgs.length - 2; i++) {
            dataArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempArgs[i + 2]);       .....however, I still get the exception at the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have 2 separate tempArgs arrays.

- One is created locally in main(), and that one prints out correctly
- the other one belongs to the class and is never instantiated.

Comment: Ok, this must be the problem. Thank you, now I can re-frame my question properly. How do I get information from an array constructed in the main method into the setup method?

Comment: option 1: create instance of your class in main, set its field, and have it go. option 2: in main, set some static field, and in setup(), copy the value form static field into an object variable

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the creation of `dataArray`.

```
@Override
public void setup() {
    // add this line
    dataArray = new int[tempArgs.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < tempArgs.length; i++) {
        dataArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempArgs[i]);
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, the `tempArgs` should be `static`, because in `main()` there is no instance of `Main` class yet, so only saving `tempArgs` will allow to use it later in `setup()`.

```
public class Main extends PApplet {
    int[] dataArray ;
    int[] normalizedData;
    static String[] tempArgs;

    ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tempArgs = new String[args.length + 2]; // note change in this line!
        ...
    }
}
```

Possibly it could be done simplier, because I see you are passing `tempArgs` to `PApplet.main()`, however I do not know how this applet framework works.

Comment: When I add that, I get the NullPointerException at that line, rather than the 'for' line, which leads me to believe that 'tempAgrs.length' is the problem, though I can't see why....

Comment: It would mean that `tempArgs` is `null`. But you allocated it in `main()`. Does the `System.out.println(tempArgs.length);` in `main()` print length correctly?

Comment: Yes, it does. I just don't know how to get the information from a string array constructed in main into another array in setup().

Comment: Ok, now I see. I do not know the contract for `PApplet.main()`. Where does it store its args, etc. You could use it then. There is another way, I'll update my answer.